# How do you message other players in Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

In Starcraft 1, it was `/w <username> <message>`, but that doesn't work anymore.  I thought they just removed that ability, but today I received a message from my opponent after our game was over.

So, how do you message players who aren't on your friends' list?

Comment: You can message an opponent from the victory screen after a game

Comment: @tzenes:  Really!?  I never noticed that!?  ..Come to think of it, I guess there wouldn't be any way to do it in general, since there can be multiple players with the same username... Alright, post that as an answer (with a picture, please - you're very good at that!) and I'll accept

Comment: I think we should just hardcode it so that any time a starcraft-2 question is asked, tzenes gets +15 reputation. :P

Comment: to be more specific, you just have to click the user's name, and hit the "chat" option.

Comment: I believe if they chat you while you are in game you can use /r to reply as well...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can message an opponent from the victory screen after a game, or from the match history:

[image]

Select the "Chat" option to start a new chat.

Comment: Anyone know if you can also do this later on, by pulling up the score screen from your match history?

Comment: @wikwocket The image you see here was pulled up from a friend's match history

Comment: Whoa, I didn't realize you could come back to this screen once it closed.  Where do you do that from?

Comment: @BlueRaja under a player's profile you can see the Match History and select any previously played game.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible anymore in Starcraft 2 by now. I can see all my replays directly in the top Navigation, but there I can only start the replyay, but no way to get the score screen again, or see the other players profile screen. I created a [Bug Report](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/sc2/topic/20752611668#1)

Comment: I started a bounty on the question on https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129880

Answer (score 0):

## Message all players, you had a match with

It is not possible from the Replay section of SC2, but you can go to your **profile** inside starcraft 2 and in your **match history** you can find and chat with all players from all matches.