# Can you see old Score Sheets ever again in SC2?

Tags: starcraft-2

After an SC2 match, a score sheet with handy graphs & stats pops up.  But, once you click 'Back' or 'Save Replay' and navigate away from it, is there no way to ever see it again?

It does not pop up again after watching the replay.  There is no visible link to it from the saved games / match history.  Is it gone forever?  That would suck, because the graphs and stats and build orders shown in that screen are cool.

Comment: See the comments to [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7179/how-do-you-message-other-players-in-starcraft-2/7182#7182)

Answer (score 7):

You can get to it from the Match History by clicking that game's entry in the list.

It's not clear how many past score sheets are saved or whether you can save them permanently, though.

Comment: This is true. I am not sure how long matches stay in the match history though, or if there is a way to permanently save them.

Comment: Good points, I included them in the answer and removed my doubt.

Comment: good question about how many games are available. I've started a new question to see if an answer can be found: [How is the number of games available in the match history tab determined?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/64179/how-is-the-number-of-games-available-in-the-match-history-tab-determined)

Comment: This doesn't seem to be possible any more in Starcraft 2 by now. I can see all my replays directly in the top Navigation, but there I can only start the replay, but no way to get the score screen again, or see the other players profile screen. How do I get contact to that other player again? I created a [Bug Report](https://us.battle.net/forums/en/sc2/topic/20752611668#1)

Comment: I found it: The "match history" is available, if you click on your Profile on the top-right corner