# How is the number of games available in the match history tab determined?

Tags: starcraft-2

When viewing a player's profile, you can see the match history for that profile.

[image: match history screenshot]

The match history does not give you access to all the games ever played under a given profile, only the most recent games.

**How is the number of games available in a profile's match history determined?** By quantity, date or some other set of factors?

Answer (score 1):

If you scroll down to the bottom you will see a button that says "Show more entries". Keep clicking this to see all of the games to my understanding. It may stop eventually, however. 
[image]

Comment: I want to know how the total number of games available in a player's match history, including those revealed by showing more entries.