# How can I contact a player I had a match with?

Tags: starcraft-2

After a match in the score screen, you can start a chat with all players from that game. But if i close the score screen, I see no possibility to contact that players again.

In the Replay tab you can only start the replay or resume the game, but no way to get the statistics back.

How can I start a Chat with a player, that I played a match before?

Is there a hidden button to contact a player from a replay?
Or maybe over Battlenet pages [like this](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/profile/1285224/1/NeoBlade/)?

Comment: I already started a bug report at https://us.battle.net/forums/en/sc2/topic/20752611668#1 but no response ;(

Comment: Match history still shows up in your profile, click on your match and then the name of the player you want to chat with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If player you want to contact was playing in a match with you,you can go to your profile inside starcraft 2 and in **your match history** you can find and chat with all players from the selected game.

If you know someones character name you can go an try to  **add friend** > character friend and type in his character name.(Not sure how it works when multiple payers share same name).

In your case if you are looking someone "popular" and active on forum you can go to starcraft 2 website and use his name in search bar,if you are lucky the results will show like **[this](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/search?q=NeoBlade)**,where you can see his full character name along  with the ID tag...Now you are back to trying to add him as a friend and trying to chat with him.

Comment: cool, I didnt know about the match history. You can even see all the statistics there, I thought they were gone, if you leave the Score screen ;)

Comment: Since some time the match history button is now in the "Replays" tab at the top, but there is no possibility to start a chat there with the player any more

Comment: And your link with a search is not working any more either.

Answer (score -4):

Click on your profile icon, then on match history. Click on the person you've just played and then add friend.

Comment: There's not really any new information here that wasn't in the existing answer two years ago. Is there a new method of reaching out to a player you've played against that hasn't already been covered?